# Stop sniffing after X seconds (instead of X packets)

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I know I can do this with scapy:

```
sniff(count=10)
```

to sniff 10 packets.

How would I go about sniffing for 10 seconds instead in python? Can scapy do this itself or do I need to wrap it some other method to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass a timeout to the `sniff` function. For more details, refer to [the official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf):

> timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None).